Why is the spelling of an English word only a rough guide to its pronunciation?
As a non-native speaker of English (and a native speaker of an Abugida language that is mostly written as it is pronounced), I always wondered how English (and similar languages) developed the spelling system that is in use today.
There are so many words that illustrate what I mean. Let's consider flatulent. Merriam-Webster suggests it be pronounced (in American English) fla-chə-lənt. This makes me wonder why that (fla-chə-lənt) is not its spelling.
I understand that it may have led to a bigger set of alphabet. It is a fact that not all sounds are adequately representable in a small alphabet. I suspect however that this feature of English comes as a surprise (even disappointment) to its new learners (native or not). This may also be a reason why the spelling system is sometimes regarded backward[1].
Of course, I am not trying to rank languages on a hypothetical (and erroneous) superiority scale. My question is more about why not choose a spelling that mimics sounds to the extent possible. Given the vast disparity between sounds and spellings of English words, it feels almost as if each English letter has a definite sound that is lost (or greatly modified) once it becomes a part of words.
Please also let me know of any books on this topic.
[1] Issac Asimov. Asimov's Guide to Shakespeare, Volume 1. Pg. vii

flatulent is pretty close to phonemic, hard to see how it could be spelled any different. But before getting to a more detailed answer, are you aware of concepts like phonemes and allophones?

“English spelling is the worst form of English spelling – except for all the others that have been tried.” — Winston Churchill

flatulent is not a good example, actually. It is pronounced according to the standard English reading rules.

The short version is that there are a lot of different factors to balance when designing an orthography, and "showing the pronunciation of unknown words" is not the highest priority for English. It's outweighed by other factors like:

Continuity. English-speakers care a lot about our language being connected to Shakespeare and Milton and Chaucer, and spelling reforms that separate us too much from that heritage tend to be unpopular.
Dialect neutrality. English's current spelling doesn't represent the pronunciation of any particular dialect very well, but that also means it doesn't really favor one dialect over another—everyone needs to memorize irregular spellings. As soon as you try to get more phonetic, you have to decide which dialects' distinctions get enshrined in spelling and which don't.
Demonstrating origins. In English, unlike some other languages, it's considered very prestigious to use loans from other languages; technical terms are almost always borrowed (or coined) from Latin or Greek even when we have perfectly good native equivalents. "Creme brulee" is a prestigious foreign word, but "crème brûlée" is even better.

As a result, we've optimized our spelling system for this rather than for ease of pronunciation. Alternatives have been proposed (look into Shavian and Deseret for a couple that had entire books published in them), but they've never caught on, due to these other factors getting in the way.

Was orthography designed with these factors in mind or is that how it appears?

@KedarMhaswade Not consciously designed with these in mind, but reforms that uphold these principles have generally been more successful than ones that don't.

@Draconis were there actually any successful systematic reforms to English spelling aside from Webster's half-baked attempt in America?

@KedarMhaswade honestly I'd say that while spelling systems can be more "designed" than spoken languages are, I tend to think that those also arise naturally and haphazardly in the majority of cases, and that was certainly the case with English. I would take Draconis' points as "objections to a possible reform", not as reasons why the spelling is the way it is. The spelling is the way it is because it evolved while English sounded much different from today, and a ton of loanwords were stuffed into the system, and once it wasn't very phonetic, it was even made worse with things like "island".

isn't it true that a large fraction of spellings can be predicted based on rules - such as [k] is spelt "ke" after long a and 'ck" after short a?

Hmmm. Actually, English spelling changed considerably since Shakespeare. I am sure, much more than Greek, or German for instance, which have more phonetic spelling. Russian has not less borrowings than English, yet all borrowings follow the Russian phonetic spelling.

I don't think English orthography was "designed". It evolved naturally from proto-Germanic and Latin roots. And, of course, there are tons of loanwords taken as is into the language.

@Lambie Proto-Germanic had no orthography. You may be confusing the language (evolved organically over time) with its writing system (we can pinpoint specific reasons why things happened or changed).

I am saying English comes from two sources. That's all. Germanic and Romance languages (Latin). So get for example is from that branch, specifically Old Norse. https://www.etymonline.com/word/get whereas arrive is from French (Latin).

@LjL -- I found something of interest -- a dictionary of the British English Spelling System by Greg Brooks: https://www.openbookpublishers.com/books/10.11647/obp.0053
